# A list of $R=T$ theorems for $\mathbf{GSp}_4$

Tags: automorphic-forms, hecke-algebras

I know of only two cases of theorem $R=T$ where $T$ is a Hecke algebra acting on an automorphic forms (or representations) space of $\mathbf{GSp}_4$, the first one was proved by A.Genestier and J.Tilouine at [Systèmes de Taylor–Wiles pour $\operatorname{GSp}_4$](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_2005__302__177_0/) and the second by V.Piloni at [Modularité, formes de Siegel, et surfaces Abéliennes](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Evincent.pilloni/Mod.pdf).

So if you know of one (or more) example of theorem $R=T$ (for $\mathbf{GSp}_4$) which is different from the two examples above, I would be very grateful if you could tell me in which paper I can find it.

**Edit:** $R$ is a deformation ring of a residual Galois representation $G_{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow \mathbf{GSp}_{4}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}})$.

Comment: What is $R$ in $R = T$?

Comment: @LSpice A Galois deformation ring (which I believe in this case should be deformations of Galois representations into $GSp_4$)

Comment: Yes exactly, I guess for people familiar with this subject there is no need to specify what $R$ is.

Comment: I guess there's a lot to be familiar with. I've been working in (a quite different part of) representation theory for over 45 years, and I didn't know what was meant.

Comment: Understand, I edit.

Comment: You should check out Calegari–Geraghty https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2019-0044 and Boxer–Calegari–Gee–Pilloni https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10240-021-00128-2.

Comment: Thank you @David.